# Limit of jump for the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

My player jumps continuously and I want to make it jump just 2 times without touching the ground ( if he touches the ground he will die) How can I restrict this ? Should I make another script? Here is the player script . I also want to make him not rotate when he fall from a box collider to another box collider . My game is a 2D game.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 300;
    public GameObject character;
    private Rigidbody2D characterBody;
    private float ScreenWidth;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Score gm;
    public bool isDead = false;
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;

    void Start()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.width;
        characterBody = character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameMaster").GetComponent<Score>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDead) { return; }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //makes player jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                RunCharacter(1.0f);
            }

            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                RunCharacter(-1.0f);
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }    

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        RunCharacter(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
#endif 
    }

    private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
    {
        characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) // this will return true if the collision gameobject has ground tag on it.
        {
            isDead = true;
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GameController.Instance.Die();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("coin"))
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            gm.score += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a counter maybe like

```c#
private int jumpCount = 0;

...

    if (jumpCount < 2 && (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)))
    {
        // You already have that reference from Start
        // should avoid to use GetComponent again
        rb2d.AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jumpCount++;
    }
```

and reset it when the player shall be allowed to jump again

```c#
jumpCount = 0;
```

probably e.g. in

```c#
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) // this will return true if the collision gameobject has ground tag on it.
    {
        isDead = true;
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GameController.Instance.Die();
    }

    jumpCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is still doesn't restrict the player to stop jumping after 2 clicks . If I click continuously the player jump continuously

Comment: @IssabelaIgnat It shouldn't .. are you sure you have set the `(` `)` of the `if` condition correctly?

Comment: I rewrite the code again and now it jumps 2 times and never jump again. It just stops

Comment: @IssabelaIgnat isn't that supposed to happen? As said I don't know what is the condition to allow the player to jump again. But as soon as you reset `jumpCount = 0;` it should be able to jump again.

Comment: The players stays on blocks , if he fall to the ground he dies , I want to allow him to jump from a block to another block 2 times , but after he jumps from the first block to the second one , he can't jump anymore , he just stay there

Comment: Oh I see so maybe you have to move the `jumpCoumt = 0;` outside of the `if` block so it gets reset on any collision. You might want to Mayne add some checks of he actually landed on top of a block or hit it from the side but this is not the scope of your question anymore. But maybe [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/473871/detect-side-of-collision.html) helps in specific [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1069611/view.html)